# Loop a user input until it passes validation

Tags: regex, linux, bash, shell

I have the following in a bash script:-

```bash
#!/bin/bash

re="/(\W|^)php[5-9]{1}.[0-9]{1}-fpm.sock(\W|$)/gm"
while ! [[ "${socket}" =~ ${re} ]] 
do
    echo "enter socket string:"
    read socket
done
```

A *valid* `$socket` string from the user would equal `php8.1-fpm.sock` using the regex we're testing for. What actually happens is, the loop continues with a user unable to break out of it despite a *valid* string?

I should be able to use my `$socket` variable in the script following a successful validation. What am I missing?

**Edit**:
Stuff I've tried:-
`re="/php[5-9]{1}.[0-9]{1}-fpm.sock/"` omitting `(\W)`

Comment: bash doesn't support `\W` in regexes.

Comment: The only purpose of `{1}` is to signal that you need help.

Comment: Try removing the perl-like slashes and flags `/` ... `/gm`

Comment: Removing the perl-like slashes and flags did the trick, thanks. `re="php[0-9]{1}.[0-9]{1}-fpm.sock"`

Comment: `{1}` can be dropped, too. The dot might need a backslash, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This could be done more correctly for the match, using standard globbing pattern matching of `case in`, with POSIX-shell grammar only.

```bash
#!/bin/sh

while case $socket in *php[5-9].[0-9]-fpm.sock) false ;; esac; do
  printf 'Enter socket string: '
  read -r socket
done
```

It could even test the socket is really an actual socket by testing `-S`:

```bash
#!/bin/sh

while case $socket in *php[5-9].[0-9]-fpm.sock) ! [ -S "$socket" ] ;; esac; do
  printf 'Enter socket string: '
  read -r socket
done
```

See `man test`:

> ```
>   -S FILE
>          FILE exists and is a socket
> ```